# Should the versions of software I use for my Wordpress development be determined by that used on the shared host?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, migration, shared-hosting

I am using UpdraftPlus premium to migrate my Wordpress site between my local computer and my shared host.  My local computer is running wamp64 server 3.0.4 with MySQL 5.7.11.  And I am developing under Wordpress 4.6.1.  However I ran into an issue doing the Wordpress migration to my shared host server running version of MySQL 5.5.51-38.2.  It failed with unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'.  I am not allowed to change MySQL on the shared host.  Further the ultimate home for the Wordpress site is on another shared host using MySQL 5.0.10.  I thought I should be developing with the latest and greatest versions of software on my local computer, but maybe that is the wrong approach.  Should I developing my Wordpress site with older versions of Wamp/MySQL/PHP/phpmyadmin to ensure that it will work on the final destination server?  How do I decide what version to use?  Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options, generally speaking if I encounter a client with overly restrictive or out of date hosting I'll recommend they move to something else, especially if it raises security concerns.

If that's not an option you can set up virtual machines (e.g. Vagrant/Virtualbox) that mirror the configuration of the servers you're working on so it has no impact on your development machine. You can set up specific versions of PHP/MySQL, specific versions of modules/extensions etc.

Comment: Thank you, Tim!  I decided to try and develop directly on the client's shared host in a sub-domain.  And used the one-click to install.  But I can see if you want to develop on your local computer that using a virtual machine is the way to go.  It just more of a cost than I am willing to incur at this time.  And again due to cost, changing the host company or plans  is not feasible right now.

Comment: Just so you know running a VM or a Vagrant box doesn't cost you a cent.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.  I will try it sometime.  But not right now. Thank you, Tim!